# Forcing time/date applet to show correct time

Tags: 14.04, unity

Ubuntu: 14.04 x86_64, all latest updates applied.

After recent time zone change, time/date applet continues to show "old" time.

tzdata package is updated. ntpd is working. date shows correct time/date. The only piece of software that refuses to abide by up-to-date timezone setting is the time/date applet.

I assume that will go away after logoff/logon or reboot, but it would mean 10-15 minutes of closing apps/restarting them  just to satisfy the misbehaving piece of software.

Is it possible to force time/date applet to show correct time without logging off/on?

Comment: I think that whatever solution you will need to restart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried following command and it helps me:

```
killall indicator-datetime-service
```

indicator applet seamlessly restart with correct time shown.